# MVC 4 [ _Layout.cshtml ] - Add all script files before page script starts

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

ASP.NET** project in Visual Studio.

I am including all `<script>` files in _Layout.cshtml file which included all external script files at the bottom... But at the same time in all the views (Eg: AboutUs, ContactUs, Products etc...), I have page related scripts at the bottom of the page.

When I render the page, I am getting script error because page script is running before jQuery/other plugins.

I have tried to put the all plugin scripts in the head section, but I do not think it is good idea...

**Now my question is:**

> Though I have page level scripts in every view, how can I place all my
>   external plugin scripts from _Layout.cshtml before page level first `<script>` tag?

**Reference image below after code is rendered...**

[image]

Using `_Layout.cshtml` file like below..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui-bootstrap.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/ui-theme.css")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/master.css")">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <h3>Header 1</h3>
    </header>

    <div id="body">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <footer>
        &copy; copyright
    </footer>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/clients-init.js")"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and my `AboutUs.cshtml` page as follows...

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "About";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<section>
    <h2>About us</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet...</p>
    <div class="showHide hide">Hello World!</div>
</section>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Page related script
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `I have tried to put the all plugin scripts in the head section, but I do not think it is good idea...` I thought this was a good idea and I am following this itself in my career. Can someone explain why this might not be a good practice??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define a section for your script by using `@RenderSection`.

First modify your `_Layout.cshtml` to look like the code below. Notice I put `@RenderSection` after all plugin script files.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/clients-init.js")"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Then, in your `About.cshtml` file you can define a section by using `@section` directive like the code below:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Page related script
        });
    </script>
}
```

By doing so, all your views those that are using `Layout.cshml` as a layout will have their scripts rendered into `scripts` section defined into the `Layout.cshtml` hence after all plugin scripts.

To learn more about layout and sections with Razor you can read this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor) by Scott Guthrie.

Comment: **@CodeNotFound** Thanks for the TIP... though it was time taking to add the code in all views, it really works... Thank you so much... I am **Accepting your answer and Up voting too**...

Comment: This would break if the view is returned as a Partial View, As we cannot user `@section` in partial views. And when the view is returned the section itself will be missing

Comment: Indeed. Section can only be used into view not in a partial. Because partial are designed to be used into a view then just put its scripts into the view.

Comment: I am using Empty project and I dont think partial view will be problem here while it wont create one..